# Storyboard View Elements Greyed Out

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode6-beta7

I'm currently trying to edit a storyboard file, in Xcode 6 (not sure if this is an Xcode bug, or if i've just done something), and when I go to the view i want to edit this is what the scene shows me :
 [image: Problem]

Is this something I've enabled accidentally? or if it's an Xcode problem. It first did this after I enabled source control for the project.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix?

Comment: If you have size classes enabled, check the device size in IB (the thing with the grid) (do not have access to Xcode right now to reproduce, but if Im not mistaken it has to do with size classes)

Comment: @Alladinian Thank you so much!, if you submit as an answer, I'll accept, but you were 100% right, thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Im glad that helped you I will submit an answer and amend with more specific info later

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The problem is probably related to Size Classes. If you have the option enabled make sure that the views were created for the size class that you have currently selected in IB (the grid thing).

Answer (score 56):

If you want to make sure it works with any width and height, find the constraint:

[image: wAny hR]

and remove it by clicking on the <kbd>x</kbd>, leaving only `installed` checked:

[image: wAny hAny]

---

I think Xcode will stop adding these automatically if you set the view to `Any Width | Any Height` in the Storyboard:

[image: storyboard bottom bar]

Answer (score 1):

Check that `Installed` is checked at the bottom of the Attributes Inspector

[image]

Comment: This is what fixed mine! Looks like I added some elements in regular width, and they were not showing up when I switched back to any width. I had to manually adjust all my constraints (mentioned by @jomo) and all my views so they all were installed for all, with no special size classes configured.