# xcode6 - Storyboard is missing files but still compiles

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have a very strange issue with storyboard, hope someone here can give me some insights.

I am working on a project in two computers. However, when I copy and paste the whole the whole project from one computer to the other, the storyboard loses all of its UI elements in the viewControllers. It still compiles with the correct UIs.

[image]

What is the issue?

Comment: This is probably related to size classes. [See a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700408/storyboard-view-elements-greyed-out)

Comment: This is related to the resources that have been added to the storyboard. You need to check the option to copy resources to the project space when the POP up to add resources appears in XCode.

Comment: You should seriously consider using git (or any other centralized versioning system) for your projects. Copying an entire project back and forth is error-prone.

Comment: @Alladinian Thank you very much for the response! I solved this problem by unchecking the "Use Size Classes" option. If you post the answer, I will accept it. Thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes, I just set it up. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: @EddieHFu You're welcome! I'll mark this question as duplicate since it's essentially the same as the linked one. Meanwhile you could upvote my answer there if you think it was helpful.