# Storyboard UI Elements not displaying in editor

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I've started building a mobile app in Xcode on the storyboard, and 2 days ago, I had all of the elements in place perfectly, but now when I open Xcode and look at the storyboard, the elements don't display and the objects in the document outline are all grayed out.

I can still deploy the app to a phone or the simulator and see the elements just fine, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the placement of the elements, but just an issue with the editor itself.

[Xcode Storyboard http://f.cl.ly/items/2B0x0z1N1D1l2P053938/Image%202014-11-13%20at%2009%3A27%3A28.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/2B0x0z1N1D1l2P053938/Image%202014-11-13%20at%2009%3A27%3A28.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700408/storyboard-view-elements-greyed-out

Comment: @Alladinian, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700408/storyboard-view-elements-greyed-out, but I think that bpolat's explanation is better than the one of the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you enable Size Classes but added the UI items for specific size. Make sure that you are on correct size by checking bottom of Interface builder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was it. I deleted some files to fit the gitignore from GitHub and one of those deleted the size configuration.