# Everything got deleted on my Xcode storyboard... Went completely blank

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash

I don't know what just happened, but I have a huge Xcode file. I saved it because I thought it was about to crash (part of the screen froze) I think re opened Xcode to get to the file again, and its all there, except when I went to the storyboard, it was ALL blank screens, with just background colors filled in... when I run it, it shows every element like it used to, and its all there, but in the storyboard, none of it is showing up, and if i click under a view controller on the left, all of the elements are grayed out and not selectable...

Help please :(

As you can see, the buttons, labels, and textfields are grayed out, and they disappeared from the view on the right: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pcz58im7tq865i/XCODE.png?dl=0

Comment: try to restart the Xcode.

Comment: @Ramshad As in Quit, and re open? I have done this 2 times already.

Comment: check here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643002/missing-ui-elements-in-xcode-6/29643757#29643757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is u used the [Size Classes](http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/12/size-classes-with-xcode-6-and-swift) in your project.
As soon as you switch from One Size class to other Size class Some of constraint and UIElement are disable as the given  Screen size is not able to fit that UI Component.

If u want to use the Size classes just flow this great tutorial [Building Adaptive User Interfaces for iOS 8](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8/)

If you don't wish to use **Size Classes** just disable it .

It will work.

To disable SizeClass select **ViewController** go to **File Inspector** and uncheck **Use Size Classes**

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I checked this off, and then back on, and everything is back. :D

Comment: Yes, excellent, Anthony Saltarelli is dead right - you turn Use Size Classes off then on again. Everything will re-appear. In my case the frames were then all wrong, but I just needed to go through each view and do "Update Frames" from the Resolve Auto Layout Issues menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try
select the views that had the wrong size and resize them to right one again by clicking on the "Any Any" button on the bottom after selecting a view.

[image]

hope this can help you.

Comment: I just added a link to a picture which describes better what the problem was... It isn't a size problem, thanks though.

Comment: See:[Storyboard View Elements Greyed Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700408/storyboard-view-elements-greyed-out)