# How to restore the main.storyboard after deleting the .xcodeproj and adding it back

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

In my iOS application I deleted the `.xcodeproj` file to remove it from git control and then I've add the same file few days later.
Now I have a storyboard which is the one from a few days and I have changed a lot on the storyboard. So how can I regenerate the correct storyboard back?
The thing is, that everything works if I start the application except that I can't work with the storyboard in this form.

For example a scene in my storyboard looks like this:

[image]

The white views are not displayed

Comment: Check its related to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700408/storyboard-view-elements-greyed-out

Comment: maybe those view are uninstalled ? Select view, go to 'Attributes inspector' and scroll to the bottom of option list, you'll see 'Installed' option.

Comment: nope they are installed. I'm pretty sure that the storyboard is broken and not compatible with the whole project. So is there a way to restore the storyboard?

Comment: omg the problem was that my view was not correct. My elements are set up for regular regular and xcode started the storyboard with any any. so all elements was display false. Puh that was close to crashing the whole project xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your Xcode project
2. Right click on the folder your want to add your Storyboard file to
3. Click `Add files to "your-project-name"...`
4. Browse to your storyboard and add it

Comment: No the problem is that the storyboard from a few days is not compatible with the .xcodeproj file and the whole project. I get views like in my edited posting.