# Why is the storyboard blank and the views are greyed out?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard

I just opened my storyboard up and all my controls are gone and the views are greyed out (SECTION A). Though the app still compiles and shows the controls in the app.

I followed this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700408/storyboard-view-elements-greyed-out) but it didn't seem to work. Removing section B only causes a red box to appear.

1. Did I do something wrong?
2. How do I get them back?
3. How do I prevent this in the future?

[image]

Comment: Change `C` to any width and regular height

Comment: That fixed it. But.... What does that do in the grand scheme of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using **size classes** without knowing about it.

If so, you should first try to understand what size classes are and how to use them. Here are some good starting points:

- [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines on Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)
- [Apple Docs on Installing and Uninstalling Views for a Size Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH11-SW1)
- [Ray Wenderlich's Adaptive Layout Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)

#### To resolve you current issue...

... and make all views appear again, first select the `(Any | Any)` size class in Interface Builder ('C' in your screenshot) and then do the following **for each** of your greyed-out views:

1. Select the view.
2. In the section to which your letter 'B' is pointing delete all rows that have some text in front of the checkbox (like "wAny hR") by clicking the ✕ in front of the row.
3. Check the checkbox of the remaining line on top (in the same section).

This will install your views for all size classes. You'll see them both in Interface Builder and at runtime in Simulator or on your device.

Unless you've understood what size classes are all about and how to make use of them always make sure that the `(Any | Any)` size class is selected in Interface Builder before making any changes to your layout. *(Because when you select a different size class and add views or constraints, those will only be added (= installed) to that particular size class and not to the others.)*